# Implement Blogger/blog post in drupal

Tags: drupal, blogs

How do I import the most recent post of a blog to drupal, along with a read more button that takes them to the blog?

Side note, I am new to drupal, I am use to codeigniter, don't like drupal very much, is there a way to access drupals views and code all manually rather than using the interface?

Comment: Your second question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to implement this by UI or coding your custom theme / module

Answer (score 0):

Views is a good choice.  You can use a module to subscribe to blog feeds, and then query the feeds you want for display using Views.